# In this code, why class style font-weight is applied, but not color?

Tags: html

why class style font-weight is applied, but not color?

It's the only issue :(

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><svg version='1.1' id='project' xmlns:svg='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'            xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'>
<style>
    .cabeceraHelp   {color:#0040FF !important;font-weight:bold;}
</style>

<g id="proyectoActual">
<rect class="tooltip_bg" id="tooltip_bg" x="0" y="0" rx="4" ry="4" width="55" height="17" visibility="hidden"/>
<text class="tooltip" id="tooltip" x="0" y="0" visibility="visible">
<tspan id="linea1ToolTip" class="cabeceraHelp" dy="15">LOREM IPSUM</tspan>
<tspan id="linea2ToolTip" dy="15">LOREM IPSUM</tspan>
<tspan id="linea3ToolTip" dy="15">LOREM IPSUM</tspan>
<tspan id="linea4ToolTip" dy="15">LOREM IPSUM</tspan>
</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this :

```css
.cabeceraHelp   {color:#0040FF !important;font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<g id="proyectoActual">
<rect class="tooltip_bg" id="tooltip_bg" x="0" y="0" rx="4" ry="4" width="55" height="17" visibility="hidden"/>
<text class="tooltip" id="tooltip" x="0" y="0" visibility="visible">
<tspan id="linea1ToolTip" class="cabeceraHelp" dy="15">LOREM IPSUM</tspan>
<tspan id="linea2ToolTip" dy="15">LOREM IPSUM</tspan>
<tspan id="linea3ToolTip" dy="15">LOREM IPSUM</tspan>
<tspan id="linea4ToolTip" dy="15">LOREM IPSUM</tspan>
</text>
</g>
```

Comment: Thaks for you quick response, Maulik, but I don't understand the difference.
The file is an svg

Comment: Your welcome @Javier , i just remove the extra </span> tag from the last.

Comment: I apologize :(
I can't see wath you tell me: i see exactly quotes in both fragments
Could yo repor the entire right code? I can´t see the difference in the snippet
Thanks

Comment: because of external resources you face this problem if you directly run this issue in fiddle, so if you directley run this example in fiddle then just remove xml & svg tag and then run it after that you will understand.

Comment: Yes, and it's running, but I'm a clumsy :) :)
Can't see the difference!!!

Comment: ok :) well If you got your desired output then just mark this question so it will helps to other and save other's time. :)